# ADO query "created by @me" doesn't show items created through copy. How do i make these show up?

Tags: azure-devops

I have created items in ADO through the left menu "+" -> "Add New Work Item"
**These items show up when I query "created by = @me"
**

From these, I needed to create variations of these work items with the same content, and use the kebab: ["Create copy of work item"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RIYw.png)
**These items do NOT show up when I query "created by = @me". **
how can I see these? If they were not create by me, but they do exists because I can see them linked as related to the original work items = who created them?? Changed by doesn't help. Although the text on the PAGE says UPDATED, and the query says CHANGED so i don't know if these actually mean the same thing since the terms are not the same.

Comment: What value is `created by` being set to on the copies? When I use the "Create copy of work item" function, my current logged-in ID is the creator. I can easily see that in the workitem list by adding `created by` in Column Options. My guess is that there are other criteria in your query that are not met by the copies.

Comment: There is one single criteria. Created by = @me

Comment: When I look at one of the tickets that is not showing up in my query, the New item in the state map has my name, and also under the follow button in the top right it says I was the last to update. I cannot find a Created By anywhere on the actual ticket in black and white. Its just assumed? i guess? from the arrow map thing.

Comment: The default work item layout doesn't show 'Created by'. In "Boards -> Work Items" or "Boards -> Backlog", click "Column Options", click "Add a column", start typing "cre", and "Created By" will be one of the suggested columns.

Comment: Hi @hvtaca, Glad to know the issue is resolved. You may consider accepting your answer that may help others encountering similar issues. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to reproduce the same issue with the preview feature of `New Boards Hubs` enabled.
[image]

My query with one single criteria of `Created by = @me` failed in displaying the WITs that I just `copied`.

As soon as I disabled the preview feature, the results began to show the missing WITs. And the issue is gone even if I enable the preview feature back.

Please have a test to disable the preview feature as of now. Besides, according to the suggestion in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/sprint-202-update#new-boards-hubs-now-available-in-public-preview), for issue related to this preview feature, you can reach out to the product engineer to send feedback via the email link shared in the document.

Hope it could mitigate the issue from your side as well.

Comment: I was very excited because I did turn this on when I logged in for the first time (clearly I'm new here). However removing Boards Hub didn't seem to change anything for me. I tried updating the query to both @me and my username and neither gave me the results.

Answer (score 0):

I was not seeing these items because the box []Query Across Projects was not checked. it looks like their isn't a top view for ADO, so this is the only way to see everything.